# how can i use pre created database in my project

Tags: android

```
package com.m;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class HellowWebView extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static final String UR_DB_NAME="mimo.sqlite";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_syid"; 
    public static final String KEY_ROWIDc = "_conid";
    static final String tableName = "CATEGORY";
    static final String New_tableName = "CATEGORY_NEW";
    static final String col_name = "NAME";
    static final String col_id = "PARENT_ID";
    static final String col_name_new = "NAME";
    static final String col_id_new = "PARENT_ID";
    public static final int version='1';
    public static Context context;

    SQLiteDatabase sql;

    public HellowWebView(Context context) {
        super(context, UR_DB_NAME, null, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        sql = context.openOrCreateDatabase(UR_DB_NAME, 0, null);
        getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + New_tableName + "(_syid INTEGER PRIMARY 
KEY,col_name_new TEXT,col_id_new NUMBER)");     
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO UR_DB_NAME.New_tableName(col_name_new,col_id_new) 
SELECT * from tableName",null);
        db.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: and ... ? I don't see a question or a problem here

Answer (score 0):

you can copy your existing db file on created db file: for this you can go as below procedure-

1. Check for existing database. (first time there is no db).
2. Create a database.
3. Now you replace your pre-created db on created db file, pragmatically.

Here is code for better reference:

```
 private boolean checkDataBase() {
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        try {
            Log.v("---DatabaseHelper--",
                    "---within checkDataBase opening database----");
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.v("---DatabaseHelper--", "---within checkDataBase----" + e);

        }

        if (myDataBase != null) {

            myDataBase.close();

        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        StringWriter errorLog = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errorLog));
        serverComm.sendErrorLog(errorLog.toString());

    }

    return myDataBase != null ? true : false;
}
```

then     getReadableDatabase(), create a blank db for your apps.. and then replace it with your db you are to place it in assets folder-

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    try {
        Log.v("---DatabaseHelper--", "---within copyDataBase----");

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(
                "DB_NAME.sqlite");
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }
        Log.v("---DatabaseHelper--", "--- after coping----");
        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        StringWriter errorLog = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errorLog));
        serverComm.sendErrorLog(errorLog.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good solution for this [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

1. Preparing the SQLite database file.

Assuming you already have your sqlite database created, we need to do some modifications to it.
If you don't have a sqlite manager I recommend you to download the opensource SQLite Database Browser available for Win/Linux/Mac.

Open your database and add a new table called "android_metadata", you can execute the following SQL statement to do it:

```
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')
```

Now insert a single row with the text 'en_US' in the "android_metadata" table:

```
INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES ('en_US')
```

Then, it is necessary to rename the primary id field of your tables to "_id" so Android will know where to bind the id field of your tables.
You can easily do this with SQLite Database Browser by pressing the edit table button Edit Table, then selecting the table you want to edit and finally selecting the field you want to rename.

After renaming the id field of all your data tables to "_id" and adding the "android_metadata" table, your database it's ready to be used in your Android application.

[image]

**Note**: in this image we see the tables "Categories" and "Content" with the id field renamed to "_id" and the just added table "android_metadata".

2. Copying, opening and accessing your database in your Android
   application.

Now just put your database file in the "assets" folder of your project and create a Database Helper class by extending the SQLiteOpenHelper class from the "android.database.sqlite" package.

Make your DataBaseHelper class look like this:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "myDBName";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

/**
  * Constructor
  * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
  * @param context
  */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
  * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
  * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

if(dbExist){
//do nothing - database already exist
}else{

//By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
//of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
this.getReadableDatabase();

try {

copyDataBase();

} catch (IOException e) {

throw new Error("Error copying database");

}
}

}

/**
  * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
  * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
  */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}catch(SQLiteException e){

//database does't exist yet.

}

if(checkDB != null){

checkDB.close();

}

return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
  * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
  * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
  * This is done by transfering bytestream.
  * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

//Open the database
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

if(myDataBase != null)
myDataBase.close();

super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

That's it.
Now you can create a new instance of this DataBaseHelper class and call the createDataBase() and openDataBase() methods. Remember to change the "YOUR_PACKAGE" to your application package namespace (i.e: com.examplename.myapp) in the DB_PATH string.

```
 ...

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {

    myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

    throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

    myDbHelper.openDataBase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

    throw sqle;

    }

    ...
```